# How to connect to firebase Realtime database from wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on chatting feature in my wordpress site. I want to use firebase realtime DB instead of sockets. But there is no proper guidance in this.

Any help will appreciated. thank you.

There is lot of info on integrating firebase to a web project but wordpress structure is different. How and where to start.

Comment: There's no Realtime Database SDK for PHP provided by Firebase. You will either have to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) or a 3rd party library that wraps it (such as [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))